# Count Number of Bills into DataTable

Tags: sql, counting

DataTable contains two columns BillId and BillValues. BillValue can be any number(1 to 1000). 
I want to count total number of 5 bill, 10 bill and all other bills appearing on DataTable and add them to Dictionary. In this regards, please advise

```
BillId , BillValue
1          5
1          10
1          10
1          5
1          20
1          5
1          4
1          10
```

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`!

Comment: after group by, how can I can how many times 5 is appearing, how many times 10 is appearing, how many times 4 is appearing etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like already said by @jarlh using the group by will do the trick

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (BillID INT, BillValue INT)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1,5),
(1,10),
(1,10),
(1,5),
(1,20),
(1,5),
(1,4),
(1,10)

SELECT BillID, BillValue, COUNT(BillId) AS n
FROM    @t
GROUP BY BillID, BillValue
```

**Result**

```
BillId  BillValue  n
--------------------
1       4          1
1       5          3
1       10         3
1       20         1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for C# Solution

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        // Assuming you fill Datatable first
        Dictionary<int, int> billCounter = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            int bill = int.Parse(dr["BillValue"].ToString());
            if (billCounter.ContainsKey(bill))
                billCounter[bill]++;
            else
                billCounter.Add(bill, 1);
        }
        // bill counter is filled with unique counters
```

Comment: Let the dbms handle this. There's no reason at all to move data from db to c# just to count. (Besides, we don't know if OP is using c#.)

Comment: Yea Agreed but when i saw question it has c# tag so just a thought :-).

Comment: First answer is more appropriate, lets Db handle all this. Using below statement to convert datatable into Dictionary
var bills = dt.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(r=>r.Field<long>(0),r=>r.Field<long>(1));